# Can I use temporary breakpoints to implement line step of a remote target

Tags: gdb

I'm working on an implement of gdb server. The server talks with gdb using RSP protocol and drive a CPU model. While developing the *line step* function (range step mode enabled) i found that my CPU model need to take some time to finish just one instruction step. The reason is the CPU model run in individual process. I have to pass the package (instruction step) through IPC. With thousands of instructions in the source line it spend too much time compared with normal running of that line.

Can I ask gdb using temporary breakpoints ( set on any possible instruction can go out of the range corresponding to the source line) to assist with step functionality? Does gdb really knows where to set the required breakpoints? If the answer is false, is there a good way to deal with this problem?

Thank you for your time!

Ted CH

Answer (score 0):

You say that you are using range-stepping mode, which would imply your gdb server already supports the `vCont` packet, and the `r` action.  See [this page](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Packets.html#Packets) for all the details.

The `r` action gives a range start and end, and you are free to step until the program counter leaves the specified range.

Your server is free to implement this as you like, so, you could place a temporary breakpoint, then resume execution until the breakpoint is hit.  But, you need to think about both control flow, and traps, both of which might cause a thread to leave the range without passing through the end point.

If passing each single step through to your simulator is slow, could you not just pass the `vCont` range information directly through to the simulator, and have the simulator stop as soon as the program counter leaves the range?  Surely this would be quicker than having multiple round trips between simulator and server.

Comment: Thank you Andrew for such a quick reply. The simulator is a commercial product that provides almost nothing but Step instruction and breakpoint APIs. So it will be difficult for the simulator to handle the range step directly. As you suggest, I can use temporary breakpoints. So the question is how to translate the start/end address into all possible hit breakpoints? Especially given the control-flow and traps you mentioned, and the fact that I think programmers might put random expressions on the same line. Is this a problem already solved in  toolchains? Do you have some references?

Comment: It's not something that GDB tries to address.  The existing range-stepping is how GDB speeds up line based stepping, but this assumes that you can adjust the target to take advantage of this, which it sounds like you can't.  You could disassemble all the instructions between start and end, spot any control flow and place breakpoints accordingly.  You still need to consider traps, but maybe you can catch them too?

Comment: Thank you Andrew! I will try to find the solution to get all the breakpoints.